# Group members can't remove folders but have write permission

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, sftp

I added user `mahsa` to group `www-data`, this user can upload or modify files inside `/var/www` but can not `rm`. 

The `www` folder's permission is `775` and it's ownership status is `www-data:www-data`, so basically `mahsa` should be able to delete contents of this folder because she belongs to `www-data` group, but when she runs `rm` command, it says `permission denied`.

We use SFTP and FileZilla.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I am confused by one thing: Are there more than one machines involved here? If the user mahsa is defined on the "server" and logged into the server, then why would they be using sftp or FileZilla? If they're not logged into the server, then adding them to a group on the server probably would have no effect. Same with adding them to a group on their client machine. I have a personal NAS. When I need to access it, I use SSH keys for the user on the NAS with the permissions I need to use. This effectively makes me a local user. Permissions don't cross machines.